# Check slot is available between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have from date and to date in database and i am sending fromdate and todate from my application i need to check weather the sent dates are already available in the database as shown in image below

[image]

I am passing 2 dates from frontend like '2023-12-13 06' to '2023-12-14 21' the output should be true since that is booked how to write query for this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE '2023-12-13 06'  between startDate and endDate
```

but this is considering only startdate how to include end date also in this query

Comment: [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+check+date+range+overlap). This is hardly a new problem.

Comment: no his table column contain dates and time too

Comment: @AsifUzZaman I am not sure what your point is - https://dbfiddle.uk/VM3RVcl2

Answer (score -1):

You maybe use this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE column name _date  between 'startDate' AND 'endDate';
```

in php coding:

```
$start_date = $_POST['s_date'];
$end_date = $_POST['e_date'];
$sql = SELECT * FROM tbl_booking WHERE column name _date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date';

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row["dates"];
}
```

Ohh, there is note:
in your sql table you need to set the date column as text than you can set or filter the value.
you dates column contain time value also. so you can try it.

Comment: You forgot to quote the string you are assigning to `$sql`. The old [mysql extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) is long gone and no one should be advocating concatenating raw user input directly into SQL queries ([SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)).